# Using firebase project ID in command prompt

Tags: firebase, cmd, command, google-cloud-functions

Command $firebase init functions after processing is not asking for my project id at firebase which should be initialized, instead it is using default project. Here is the picture [image]

Answer (score 2):

It is because you are **reinitializing** the firebase functions in the current directory i.e. **learning chatbots**. [image]

If you intend to overwrite the existing firebase functions in this directory you can follow these instructions:
[image]
OR if don't want to overwrite existing files:[image]

**It will be better if you create a new directory and then initialize firebase functions there.**

> Make a new directory **outside of "learning chatbots"** directory and
>   try initializing there.

Comment: Updated the answer! Try using this.